# Cannot access UITabBarController from modal ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController`-based application in which my **login page** is presented modally by the default tab's VC(UITabBarController index 0), and is dismissed modally by `dismissViewControllerAnimated:`.

From my **settings page** I have a *logout* button, and if the user immediately logs back in I have to call `[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and then reset the `UITabBarController`'s **selectedIndex** property in order to get rid of the settings page and also go back to the starting tabBar tab. So I do this:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    /*Succesful Login*/
    if([responseString isEqualToString:@"success"])
    {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.presentingViewController;

        if (tabBarController){
            NSLog(@"I have a tab bar~");
            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"I don't have a tab bar~");
        }

        //dismisses from a second, immediate, re-login attempt
        [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        //dismisses from first login attempt
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        NSLog(@"Succesful login.");
    }
```

In this case, the method `setSeletedIndex:` does not work because this methodology essentially creates a new instance of the tabBarController, when it is the original that is actually displayed. I CAN NOT seem to access the **already existing** `UITabBarController` which was before my modally presented login page.

**EDIT:**

I have tried using this conditional to check its existence:

```
if (self.tabBarController){
    NSLog(@"I have a tab bar~");
    //[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"I don't have a tab bar~");
}
```

where I have even changed **self.tabBarController** to self.presentingViewController.tabBarController and get nil, and self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.tabBarController and get nil, how am I to access the previously existing `UITabBarController`?

*Objective:* Access the application's UITabBarController that is present before the presentation of the login page. (Access the Appdelegate's UITabBarController)

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would create a new instance of a tab bar controller. If you log self.presentingViewController and self.tabBarController what do they give you? Also, from your description, it sounds like you already are on the tab at index 0 (which presented the modal), so what do you expect that setSelectedIndex:0 is going to do?

Comment: found the answer, and self.tabBarController is what was giving me nil, that was the problem..

Comment: Your question was unclear. Be considerate that folks took their time to try to help you. The least you can do is to clarify your question to make it easier to help you with a "Solution." Good luck.

Comment: No I appreciate the help and am sorry for the unclarity, This is the first time I've had to deal with this and it's been really confusing. I've had to reconfigure my entire app, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is a natural fit for delegation.

In the header file for your Login, define a delegate. E.g.,

```
@class Login
@protocol LoginDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) userDoneWithLoginController:(Login *) controller;
@end

@interface Login: UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<LoginDelegate> viewDelegate;

@end
```

Then your presenting view controller segue can set itself as the delegate to the login view controller by setting this "viewDelegate" object inside the prepareForSegue for the presenting view controller before control passes to the Login page. [Let me know if you want this clarified.]

In addition the presenting view controller will implement the required method--which can simply dismiss the login page when called

```
-(void)  userDoneWithLoginController:(Login *) controller
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Once you've done this, the login page simply calls its delegate method when it is done, thusly:

```
[self.viewDelegate userDoneWithLoginController:self];
```

Viola!

This is preferred way to dismiss a modal view in iOS. The calling controller should be the controller dismissing the view. Try to avoid having view controllers dismiss themselves. Instead, have their calling/presenting controllers (delegates) dismiss them.

Comment: This is great and all, but this is not the solution to this problem, try reading the edit again. I don't care about preferred dismissal technique right now.. I'm in prototyping stage. I just need to access the UITabBarController that was visible directly before the presentingViewController

Comment: What's wrong with passing it to the viewcontroller being presented? You can pass the tabBarController as a variable if you want to do what you described.

Comment: It requires more effort because you're using segues and `prepareForSegue:`. I'd rather keep it strictly programmatic and simply access the tabBarController from my appDelegate.

Comment: I am confused by you last comment. Did you really mean that setting a variable required more effort?

Comment: No sorry, I meant that reconfiguring my setup to follow your methodology is more effort. I currently am not using segues for the login, it is all done modally and programmatically. Setting the variables in the way that you do is good, but would require a segue and `prepareForSegue:`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work.

```
// check that the vc presenting your current modal vc is a tab bar controller
if ([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {

    // get the pointer of type UITabBarController
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.presentingViewController;

    // set to the desired tab
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
}

// dismiss the current modal vc
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found my solution.

I was able to access the app's `UITabBarController` from the **Appdelegate** like so:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[appDelegate myTabBar] setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Comment: This might work, but I wouldn't call it a solution, it's more of a work-around. You shouldn't have to do it like this. Did you try the logging I suggested in my comment?

Comment: Ahh I see what I left out of the problem... the **settings page** is accessed from the navBar of the tabBar's 3rd index(index 3). Therefore when self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController(the 3rd tab) dismisses the login(along with the settings), it leaves the tabBar on index 3.. which needs to be 0.